# How to use paperjs in ace live editor?

Tags: ace-editor, paperjs, livecoding

In paperjs, you need to associate canvas element for the js file:

```
<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas">
      //your code
</script>
```

I wonder how i could do this in [ace](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace) (live coding editor)?

I have a canvas and also the editor in the same page, and i want to code in the editor to control the canvas.
How could i do that?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do exactly this over at http://sketch.paperjs.org/
Look at the createPaperScript () function in http://sketch.paperjs.org/assets/js/editor.js

Comment: wow, thx and you guys must to be genius to even consider this!